# How would a musician travel from Venice to Dresden around 1700?

Tags: europe, 18th-century, 17th-century, travel, holy-roman-empire

I'm writing a historical fiction TV pilot and I need some help from the history buffs here. One of my characters, a young, aspiring, musician needs to travel from Venice to Dresden, Germany. I suspect it more likely that he took some part of journey by water. Can anyone offer information about how people travelled this route around 1700?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the musician trying to travel as fast as possible (no expense spared) or leisurely/cheaply?

Comment: The main route would be: Venice, [Mountain crossings], Vienna, Brünn, Prague, [Mountain crossing Bad Schandau], Dresden. These would have been long established trade routes. No major waterways along the way.

Comment: The musician has limited funds and is trying to get there is a reasonable time frame to audition for a month long festival event. Dresden is on the river Elbe, so I'm thinking perhaps he would do part of the journey by boat? Were there no canals connecting the Elbe to other parts of Europe around 1700?

Comment: From Prague, the river Moldau flows north into the Elbe and from there on to Dresden. No idea if possible per boat in 1700. Look for Casanova's trip from Dresden through Prague and Vienna on to Venice between October 1752 and May 1753. Details may give a hint on how he traveled between the cities.

Comment: According to [this site](https://www.zum.de/whkmla/sp/0910/hong/hong1.html#:~:text=In%20France%20in%20the%2017th,using%20pound%20locks%20(2).), the first major canal in Germany was opened in 1669.

Comment: After a (very) swift review of: [Die Kanalisierung von Moldau und Elbe an der Wende vom 19. zum 20. Jahrhundert](https://phaidra.univie.ac.at/download/o:1267401) (PDF, in German), serious planning for a Donau/Moldau/Elbe connection only started in the early 19th century. Most references about the shipping on the Elbe (north of Dresden) before 1800 is about the shipping of goods. I think one can rule out passenger transport in this area in 1700.

Comment: @KateBunting That link references areas in Brandenburg, Prussia and not in Saxony (Dresden).

Comment: @RiddleLeafFilms Travelling was very expensive at the time. Not just for the cost of transportation but most of all lodging for the night. One way to save on lodging was through connections. Therefore being a guest of relatives / friends but also religious groups. Proper letters of introduction / patronage would be needed.

Comment: @Mark Johnson According to [this article](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dresden-Teplitzer_Poststra%C3%9Fe) the road from Prague to Dresden would cross the Erzgebirge rather than the Elbsandsteingebirge. The article also has a map in which thr Elbe valley looks pretty impassable for stagecoaches.

Comment: @Jan Yes, the **Alte Dresden-Teplitzer Poststraße** (through **Fürstenwalde**, Pass am Geiersberg) would be the main crossing point in 1700 (until 1860). The **Neue Dresden-Teplitzer Poststraße** (through Peterswald, Nollendorf Pass) starting 1810. [Erzgebirgspässe - Entwicklung des Botenwesens und der Poststraßen, Pass am Geiersberg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erzgebirgsp%C3%A4sse#Pass_am_Geiersberg). Bad Schandau, as a railways crossing, after 1850.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The map I linked to in my answer ist from 1720 or so and its road from Dresden to Teplice and/or Aussig/Usti n.L. goes through (Pirna-)Zehista and Peterswald/Petrovice.

Comment: @Jan Yes, I saw that. But the *Pass am Geiersberg* was the main route at the time. The Nollendorf Pass was possible but difficult (see the 1794 note in the link).

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://collections.thulb.uni-jena.de/rsc/viewer/HisBest_derivate_00011015/C-390_01.tif) is a roughly contemporary map (from [1727](https://collections.thulb.uni-jena.de/receive/HisBest_cbu_00026429)) with postal routes that includes both Venice and Dresden. This does not yet mean your character would actually take any of these routes (e.g. because there were cheaper modes of transportation?) but it might be a start.

Please note that according to the map legend, routes drawn with a single line are for post riders ("reitende Posten") and routes drawn with duplicate lines are for coaches, carts or the like ("fahrende Posten").

Comment: Typo: "postal". So from the map, a hypothetical route would be Venice - Palmanova - Laubach (Ljubljana) - Gratz (Graz) - Vienna - Prague - Dresden.

Answer (score -1):

The main route would be: Venice, [Mountain crossings], Vienna, Stockerau (north bank of the Danube outside of Vienna), Prague, [Mountain crossing [Pass am Geiersberg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erzgebirgsp%C3%A4sse#Pass_am_Geiersberg)], Dresden.

These would have been long established trade routes.

- **Alte Dresden-Teplitzer Poststraße**

  - through *Pass am Geiersberg* and **Fürstenwalde** until 1860

    - pink, left route

[image]

No major waterways along the way in 1700.

From Prague, the river Moldau flows north into the Elbe and from there on to Dresden.

Serious planning for a Donau/Moldau/Elbe connection only started in the early 19th century. Most references about the shipping on the Elbe (north of Dresden towards Hamburg) is about the shipping of goods.

---

**Sources**:

- [Erzgebirgspässe - Entwicklung des Botenwesens und der Poststraßen, Pass am Geiersberg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erzgebirgsp%C3%A4sse#Pass_am_Geiersberg) (in German)
- [Die Kanalisierung von Moldau und Elbe an der Wende vom 19. zum 20. Jahrhundert](https://phaidra.univie.ac.at/download/o:1267401) (PDF, in German)

Answer (score -1):

Working from [the map posted by @Jan,](https://collections.thulb.uni-jena.de/rsc/viewer/HisBest_derivate_00011015/C-390_01.tif) the route would be:

- Depart Venice to Laubach (optionally Klagenfurt via Burgo and Brixen);
  The route through Klagenfurt would be inhospitable in winter, but perhaps more scenic in summer.
  [image]
- Depart Laubach for Vienna, via Gratz and Loeben (meeting up with any travelers through Klagenfurt);
  [image]
- Depart Vienna for Linz;
  [Linz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linz) is the only Danube crossing between Vienna itself and Passau. Crossing at Vienna takes one into Moravia through Olmutz (ie Austerlitz) and then into Silesia via Breslau - a very roundabout route, but possible.
  [image]
- Depart Linz for Prague;
  Shortly after leaving Linz one descends into the [Moldau/Vitava river valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vltava), which flows into the Elbe at Prague. This stretch has only ever been intermittently navigable, so travel would have been on foot, horseback, or carriage.
  [image]
- Depart Prague for Dresden;
  One is now simply following the [Elbe river valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbe). The Elbe has always been navigable by commercial vessels as far inland as Prague, according to Wikipedia, so this could be a comfortable downstream river excursion.
  [image]

Comment: *The Elbe has always been navigable by **commercial** vessels* is what Wikipedia states. Also the needed locks only came about in the 19th century according to the source given in my answer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Thank you. I've made the correction.

Comment: There is a northern route from Vienna )through Stockerau) that goes directly to Prague, so going over Brünn (Brinn on the map) or Linz is an unlikely option.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Until much later than 1809, there was no Danube crossing between Vienna and Linz. Yes, one can always trek overland; but that's not how city folk, such as musicians, travel. Check out Napoleon's 1805 and 1809 campaigns post-Vienna, for an idea of the difficulties of that route you favour.

Comment: The northern route to Prague starts at the north side the Danube at Enzersdorf, across from  Vienna.

Comment: The map is a bit misleading as it gives mainly postal lines, not general streets (Landstraßen) its main focus. But there always was a "Prager (Land)Straße" between Vienna and Prague, and you can see it in the map as a double dotted line via Stockerau - Znaim - Stocken (Štoky) - Kuttenberg (Kutna Hora). Its route is basically the same as modern day auto routes S3 - E59 - I38 - I12.

Comment: In case you couldn't identify it, the town at the northwest border of Vienna nowadays is called [Langenzersdorf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langenzersdorf) and in late-17th century had the name Langen-Enzersdorf.